# Register_post and add_menu & add_submenu conflict?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want use register_post to get wordpress template for create my own post.

```
 $product_label = array(

  'name' => __('Products','neocom'),
  'singular_name' => __('Product','neocom'),
  'add_new' => __('Ajout d\'un nouveau produit','neocom'),
  'add_new_item'    => __('Ajout d\'un nouveau produit 2','neocom'),
  'new_item'    => __('Ajout d\'un new produit','neocom'),
  'edit_item'   => __('Edit produit','neocom'),
  'view_item'   => __('View product','neocom'),
  'all_items'   => __('Liste des produits','neocom'),
  'not_found'   => __('Pas de produits enregistré'),
  'menu_name' => __('My product name menu','neocom'),

);


register_post_type('product', array(
 'labels' => $product_label,
 'singular_label' => __('Product'),
 'public' => true,
 'show_ui' => true,
 'capability_type' => 'post',
 'show_menu_ui' => 'neo-product',
 'hierarchical' => false,
 'supports' => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail')
));
```

I want to do appear List's product and New product and my own admin menu. I have added show_menu_ui => 'neo_product'. The result , i have my product list but haven't new product.
I have defined admin_menu like it :

```
add_action('admin_menu',array($this,'buildMenuAdmin')); // On my constructor
```

buildMenuAdmin function :

```
 add_menu_page('NeoptinCom','Neo_Com',$capability,'neo-product',array(&$this,'neoproduct_all'));

 // Gestion page product & hook pour le css
    //Page product ( Liste )
    $product_page = add_submenu_page('neo-product', __('All Product','neocom'), __('Products','neocom'),$capability,'neo-product',array(&$this,'neoproduct_all'));
    add_action( 'admin_head-'.$product_page, array(&$this,'admin_header') );

// Page Creation/Modification de produit
$product_page_create = add_submenu_page('neo-product', __('Create Product','neocom'), __('Create Product','neocom'),$capability,'neo-product-create',array(&$this,'neoproduct_create'));
add_action( 'admin_head-'.$product_page_create, array(&$this,'admin_header') );
error_log('Page=> '.$product_page_create );
//Page paiement
$paiement_page = add_submenu_page('neo-product', __('Paiement','neocom'), __('Paiement','neocom'),$capability,'neo-paiement',array(&$this,'neopaiement'));
add_action( 'admin_head-'.$paiement_page, array(&$this,'admin_header') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the issue is. You don't need all that extra code, just the first block of code, and you will have the list all and new product options within that menu item. I copied the first block of code you supplied and that alone works fine.

Changed from comment to answer.